# How to split dynamic content into multiple columns at bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have three div:

```
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-4"></div>
```

Inside first div, there are 2 items with a "add new" button. by every click on the "add new" button, a new item is created. So, the structure is like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
   <p>Item 1</p>
   <p>Item 2</p>
   <button>Add New</button>
</div>
```

Now, I want, when first column contain 5 elements, it'll stop adding new item on that div. So, "add new" button will be showed at second column then and 6th item will be added on the second column too. Thus, from 11th item, they'll be added on last column. After 15th item, no item will be added.

So, the visualization is like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I make the functionality? [Here is my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znak2j0x/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think that you have an `m x n`table, in this case 5 x 3.

Go fill per column first:

```
var count = $('.single').length,
    $cols = $('.col-xs-4'),
    maxPerColumn = 5;

$('body').on('click', '.add-new', function(event) {  
    // We stop at 3 * 5 = 15 this way
    if(count >= ($cols.length * maxPerColumn))
        return;

    // Math.floor(count / maxPerColumn) is the integer division between current item count,
    // and max items allowed per count - will go from 0 to 14 / 5 = 2, remainder 4.
    $cols.eq(Math.floor(count / maxPerColumn)).append($('.single').eq(0).clone());
    count++;

});

$('body').on('click', '.remove', function() {  
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

[Check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4u1rdqou/2/) - further behaviour, like on item removal,  is left to you.

Comment: This is good. But, after "removing" some item, it don't work well, like if I remove two items from 1st column, instead of 5 items adding on that column, 3 items are adding by "Add new" button.

Comment: @user1896653 `further behaviour, like on item removal, is left to you ` : ))